# Output of a sum integer from a function that iteratively minimizes an arrary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to build a function (minSum) to minimize the sum of an array, of various lengths and values over any number of iterations.

The function contains two arguments - the name of an array (num) and the number of steps of modification (k). For each k-step of modification, the function will retrieve an element/integer from the num array, divide it by 2, and update the array with the ceiling of the halved value in the same index position as it was retrieved. Once the k value has been reached, the function should output the sum of the array as a single integer.

For example - if my array (num) is [10. 20. 7] and I will run it over 2 steps (k) the input for the function would be minSum(num, 2).
It would divide 10 by half in kstep 0 resulting in an array of (5, 20, 7)
It would divide 10 by half in kstep 0 resulting in an array of (5, 10, 7)
It would divide 10 by half in kstep 0 resulting in an array of (5, 10, 4) (4 being the ceiling of 3.5).
The output of this would be the sum 0f 5, 10, 4 = 19. By increasing the k-value we should be able to reduce the output to a lower value. In any case, I'm able to use the below code to achieve my goal with the exception of the output being a single integer (our testing system system only receives the final array). Any pointers here? Thanks!

```
import array as ar
import math
import numpy as np


#  1. INTEGER_ARRAY num
#  2. INTEGER k (number of steps of element removal, transformation and update)


def minSum(num, k):
    arr = np.array(num)
    i = 0
    idx = 0
    while i < k:
        for element in np.nditer(arr):
            thereduced = math.ceil(element/2)
            np.put(arr, [idx], thereduced)
            if i < arr.size-1:
                idx += 1
            thesum = int((sum(arr)))
            i = i+1         
    return thesum
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum() method returns a single value, so you might create an empty array, put the "thesum" value into the array and at the end of the function return the new array with the values, right now your code is just returning a single integer

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm seeing locally - just an integer. That's what the test case requires but the code keeps failing because it sees the output as an integer.
I've also dinged the QA people to see if it's something on their end.

Comment: just create that list and fill it with the values, I guess that is what you are looking for, however, as you just say, you must be sure what exactly are they expecting on their end, any example input will do it. Hope it helps